# Remove last 5 characters with Field Calculator in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser, vbscript

I wonder how to delete a word (or the last 5 characters) using the field calculator in ArcGIS 10.2.
I have a column such as:

Paris City;
London City;
Berlin City

I need to remove "City", to be left with Paris, London, Berlin.

Any tips on doing this automatically?

Comment: Do a find and replace on the field when in table view mode. Click on the options button in top left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the python parser type:

```
!Field_name![:-5]
```

That should return all but the last five characters regardless of what they are.

This uses [Python slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation).

Answer (score 8):

In the field calculator choose `Python Parser` and write the following formula:

```
!Field_Name!.replace(" City","")
```

Where: !Field_Name! is the name of the field that contains city names.